# sequelize interprets date with hour = 2

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use sequelize to search for a record in my database based in a date field:

date_from2 is this value:

```
2017-01-09
```

and sequelize interprets its as a date with hour = 2:

```
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `date`, `total_visits`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `table1` AS `table1` WHERE `table1`.`user_id` = 123 AND `table1`.`date` = '2017-01-09 02:00:00' LIMIT 1;
```

And it creates a new record everytime, instead of updating it.
When it inserts, the date is inserted with this value:

```
2017-01-09 00:00:00
```

This is my code:

```
where = { user_id: user_id,
                  date: date_from2
                 };

        values = {
                    user_id: user_id,
                    date: date_from2,
                    total_visits: total_visits

                };

        Model.findOne({where: where}).then(function (record) {
            if (!record) {
                // Item not found, create a new one
                Model.create(values)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('created!');
                    }).error(function (err) {
                        console.log('error on create');
                    });
            } else {
                // Found an item, update it
                Model.update(values, {where: where})
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('updated!');
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log('error on update');
                    });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is your time zone UTC+0200?

Comment: hm, yes. How can i solve this? @RobG

Comment: @RobG The UTC is -02

Comment: Ok, so "2017-01-09" is being treated as local (i.e. "2017-01-09 00:00:00-02:00") and being storing it as UTC (i.e. "2017-01-09 02:00:00Z"). You need to do comparisons using the same time zone, probably jjbskir has your answer.

Comment: yes, i did this. jjbskir answer is not correct because I'm storing time series data. For the same user I have different values depending on date.

Answer (score 0):

Query by just using the user's `user_id` and not the `date` if you are trying to get a specific user:

```
Model.findOne({where: {user_id: user_id}})
```

The issue is that it's storing the `date` differently then what you are passing in. Because of this you were never able to find the existing user and you kept creating new ones. There is nothing wrong with using `UTC` timezone and you should be able to convert this to any other time zone.

Comment: date is important here, because is a time series data. for the same user i have different values, the only diference is the date